# Infinite Scrolling in both directions - fetch different data when scroll up and down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, fetch-api

I need something that allows me to fetch data when I scroll up and down. First I display today events and when scroll up, I need to fetch previous information and when I scroll down to fetch next events. I've found **react-infinite-scrolling-component**, but it works only in one direction. Does anyone has a better idea?

Comment: why need to get scroll up event, when scroll down then store data in state and when scroll up show that data no need to call api !

Comment: when scroll up, I need to get an information that was never randed. first I get today events only, scroll up->fetch yesterday events and  scroll down->fetch tomorrow events

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Elma did you got any solution for your the problem ?